# Why is $\int_{N+1}^{\infty}x^{-s}dx = \frac{(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $$\int_{N+1}^{\infty}x^{-s}dx = \frac{(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1}$$

*) Assume $s>1$, $N+1$ term is fixed.

I tried to use Newton-Leibniz Theorem but without success. I bet it's should be easy but I'm new with integration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int x^{-s}dx = \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s},$$
$$\int_{N+1}^{\infty}x^{-s}dx = \lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{N+1}^M x^{-s}dx=
\lim_{M\to\infty}\frac{M^{1-s}}{1-s}-\frac{(N+1)^{1-s}}{1-s}=\cdots
$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin.

Comment: Is there a reason for down-voting?

Comment: @AlonAlon, vengeance by the answer to another question. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027387/how-to-generalize-the-riemann-hypothesis/1027874#1027874.